# Silverlight control locked in runtime

Tags: silverlight, controls

I have a online survey running in Silverlight. Out of more than 1000 onetime users, there are three users than cannot open a combobox on the first page. The control seems disabled and don't react on mouseclick.

Since it is one-time user, they don't wan't to help me with debugging and I cannot reproduce the problem myself.

Any ideas why 1000 users have no problem, and 3 are experiencing all controls like they were disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Jake, it would be hard to tell if the users aren't giving you any type of information like OS/Browser, screenshots, etc.  I don't think there would be a general reason especially since you said yourself that 3 out of 1000 had the problem.

Comment: Tim thanks for answering. I'm now up on 2000 onetime users. One of the three users with the 'lock' problem wrote back that it worked the next day? I did not update anything... Another of the problem user wrote he used IE 8 and still have the problem. Anyway 2 out of 2000 users are ok and the customer stopped whipping me :).